# I am creating a controller for my sign in route but i amfacing an error in terminal

Tags: node.js, express, mern

I am creating an e-commerce website on MERN stack and i am a beginner. While writing code for controller of my signin route  i am getting this error.

```
C:\Users\AbTorres9\Desktop\MERN\projbackend>node start
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\AbTorres9\Desktop\MERN\projbackend\start'
←[90m    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:982:15)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:864:27)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)←[39m
←[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47←[39m {
  code: ←[32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'←[39m,
  requireStack: []
}
```

while here is the code for my controller:

```
const User = require("../models/user");
const { check, validationResult } = require("express-validator");
var jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
var expressJwt = require("express-jwt");

exports.signup = (req, res) => {
  const errors = validationResult(req);

  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return res.status(422).json({
      error: errors.array()[0].msg
    });
  }

  const user = new User(req.body);
  user.save((err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        err: "NOT able to save user in DB"
      });
    }
    res.json({
      name: user.name,
      email: user.email,
      id: user._id
    });
  });
};

exports.signin = (req, res) => {
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  const { email, password } = req.body;

  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return res.status(422).json({
      error: errors.array()[0].msg
    });
  }

  User.findOne({ email }, (err, user) => {
    if (err || !user) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        error: "USER email does not exists"
      });
    }

    if (!user.autheticate(password)) {
      return res.status(401).json({
        error: "Email and password do not match"
      });
    }

    //create token
    const token = jwt.sign({ _id: user._id }, process.env.SECRET);
    //put token in cookie
    res.cookie("token", token, { expire: new Date() + 9999 });

    //send response to front end
    const { _id, name, email, role } = user;
    return res.json({ token, user: { _id, name, email, role } });
  });
};

exports.signout = (req, res) => {
  res.json({
    message: "User signout"
  });
};
```

I have also installed all of the modules which are mentioned in the json file but still i am facing this error and i am unable to debug these errors as i am still very much new in programming but i am determined to learn and get better by time. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have your entrypoint file named as `start`, I think you mean to be doing `npm start` which will run the `start` script in your `package.json`.

This error `Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\AbTorres9\Desktop\MERN\projbackend\start'` is happening because you're using the command `node start` which will try to start your server looking for a file in the current directory named `start`, which doesn't exist, hence the error

If you defined your Express server code in a file named `app.js`, for example, you could start that by running `node app.js`

Comment: thank you for your response, then how should i proceed. I always run my code using npm start.

Comment: @ABHISHEKBARTHWAL does `npm start` not work for you? The error you posted is of you trying to run the command `node start`. If you have a `start` script defined in `package.json`, `npm start` is the way to go

Comment: thank you, you are a saviour. Stack overflow is the best. Really reallyn thanks a lot @awarrier99

Comment: @ABHISHEKBARTHWAL no problem